# Tableau Desktop Customize Download Button

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I have a report that my users can view and download but I only want to
limit the download button to x number a day before disabling it.

Searched high and low for solutions, are there any ways to handle this problem?

Javascript, HTML, not very well documented and chatgbt is just driving me around the bush

Comment: if you are going to the trouble to write Javascript and HTML, you can provide your own Export button outside of Tableau, coded in JavaScript and use Tableau's Embedding API to make your button appear integrated with the Tableau viz, and to customize the behavior as desired. Usually, there are easier ways to do things staying 100% in Tableau, but if you need to do something differently, a bit of API code can be just the ticket.

Comment: As im publishing it to Tableau Server, Javascript/HTML not really working as I have to work within Tableau. if im not wrong, Tableau does not have such function within

Comment: I would suggest you to create a parameter control and limit the number of rows per page then create Index() calculation that should help you. visit  https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/how-to-limit-the-number-of-rows-displayed?lang=en-gb  for detailed solution